# Shema Text not consistent

Tags: shema, bircas-krias-shema

In the first paragraph of the Shema we say you need to love Hashem בכל לבבך ובכך נפשך ובכל מאדך, to love Hashem with all your heart, soul, and resources. But in the second paragraph of Shema, it says “and if you listen to what I commanded you to do, to love Hashem בכל לבבכם ובכל נפשכם”. So basically, what happened to מאדך and why was it excluded in the second paragraph of Shema?

Comment: See Nefesh Hachaim for a deep explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Kli Yakar](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Deuteronomy.11.13.1?lang=bi) asks this question and answers based on the fact that the first parsha refers to a single person and this parsha refers to the tzibbur. He then explains why all the interpretations of מאדך don’t apply to a tzibbur:

> ומ"ש בכל לבבכם ובכל נפשכם ולא נאמר ובכל מאדכם לפי מה שפירש"י שלכך נאמר בכל מאדך לפי שיש לך אדם שממונו חביב עליו מגופו, מדקאמר יש לך אדם ש"מ שדבר זה בלתי מצוי כ"א באדם אחד או מתי מספר שבטלה דעתם אצל כל אדם אבל לא בציבור כי לא שכיח הדבר שרבים יסכימו על דעה נפסדה זו. ולפי מה שפירש"י בכל מאדך בכל מדה שהוא מודד לך להרע או להטיב, הרי פרשה זו מדברת מזמן קבלת השכר והוא עת דודים ואין שייכת הברכה שעל הרעה לכאן כי אינה כפי הזמן אשר הוא עומד בו. ועוד נראה שאין צורך לומר כאן שיעבוד ה' בכל מדה שהוא מודד לו אפילו בזמן קבלת הרע, לפי שדבר זה כבר אמור הוא בפרשה זו שנאמר ואבדתם מהרה מעל הארץ וגו', ושמתם את דברי אלה על לבבכם. ר"ל שאפילו בזמן שצאן אובדות יהיו מ"מ יעבדו את ה' על כל פנים וישימו דבריו על לבבם וכן פירש"י (יא יח), וא"כ ענין זה אמור בפירוש לכך לא הוצרך לומר ובכל מאדכם

Comment: Wasn’t able to understand every single word but basically he says that the second paragraph is referring to the congregation as a whole, and since most people don’t value their money over their life we don’t say “me’odechem”?

Comment: Yes. Furthermore, according to the second interpretation of Rashi that it means to serve Hashem with all situations, good or bad, he explains that this parsha is actually discussing punishment and saying to continue serving Hashem, therefore it didn’t say it.